# Form validation run() = always false

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have this code:

```
$update['recipe_name'] = $this->input->post('recipename');
    $update['recipe_description'] = $this->input->post('recipedescription');
    $update['recipe_instruction'] = $this->input->post('recipeinstruction');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($update['recipe_name'], 'Name of '.$update['recipe_name'], 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($update['recipe_description'], 'Description of '.$update['recipe_name'], 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($update['recipe_instruction'], 'Instruction of '.$update['recipe_instruction'], 'trim|required');

    for($count=0;$count<$update['total_ingredients'];$count++)
    {
    $ingredient_inputs['id'] = $this->input->post('id'.$count);
    $ingredient_inputs['name'] = $this->input->post('ingredient'.$count);
    $ingredient_inputs['quantity'] = $this->input->post('quantity'.$count);
    $ingredient_inputs['measurement'] = $this->input->post('measurement'.$count);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($ingredient_inputs['name'],'Name of '.$ingredient_inputs['name'], 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($ingredient_inputs['quantity'], 'Quantity of '.$ingredient_inputs['name'], 'trim|required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($ingredient_inputs['measurement'], 'Measurement of '.$ingredient_inputs['name'], 'trim|required');

    $update['ingredients'][$ingredient_inputs['id']] = array('componentname'=>$ingredient_inputs['name'],
    'quantity'=>$ingredient_inputs['quantity'],'unit'=>$ingredient_inputs['measurement']);
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {

    }
```

I don't know whats wrong with my code or if the looping of set_rules are messing it up. It doesnt show any error, it just always false when i run the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `set_rules()` method should be the name of the field not what your user entered.

Comment: I got overwhelmed and overlooked that part. 

damn. I shouldv noticed it.

Comment: Is the 2nd parameter required?

i really want to leave it empty.

Comment: Yes you should set it